# Ajax request shows status of 200 in console but executing the error function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my `index.php` file I have the following script that sends an `ajax` request:

```
$('#select-name').on('change', function () {
    var selectedName = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
           url: "assets/php/selectCar.php",
          data: {
                   selectedName: JSON.stringify(selectedName)
                },
      dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json",
       success: function (data) {
                   $.each(data, function (i, value) { 
                        $('.car-model').append('<option value = "'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
                    });
                },
         error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
     });
});
```

The element with id `select-name` in the **index.php** file looks like:

```
  <select name="car-name" id="select-name" class="form-control">
     <option value="select_make">Choose make</option>
     <?php 
         $stmt = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM car_name";
         if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt)) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo '<option value = "'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
             }
         }
      ?>
  </select>
```

And the `php` statement in the above code works fine and renders the elements. The `selectCar.php` in which the request is sent to looks like:

```
<?php
    require 'db.php';
    $selectedName = $_POST['selectedName'];
    $stmt = "SELECT DISTINCT model FROM model WHERE id IN ( SELECT model_id FROM cars WHERE name_id IN ( SELECT id FROM car_name WHERE name = '".$selectedName."'))";

    $models = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $models[] = $row['model'];
    }
    echo json_encode($models) ;
?>
```

I have tested the `sql` statement substituting the value of `$selectedName` with the value I get when I alert `selectedName` in the script.
I have no idea why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit:- I have logged the error in the console and I see :

```
responseText: "<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: selectedName in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/wabi-cars/assets/php/selectCar.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />\n[]"
```

and line 3 of `selectCar.php` is `$selectedName = $_POST['selectedName'];`

Comment: It’s important that you provide a minimum viable replication steps. What is the error outputted from the catch callback?

Comment: The error callback also gets triggered, if a `parsererror` occurs. With `dataType: "json"` you instruct jQuery to parse the response as JSON - but if what your script returned is not valid JSON, then you end up in the `error` callback, no matter what the HTTP status code said. Check what _output_ your script actually responded with, not just the status code.

Comment: @CBroe I have made the edit

Comment: And line 3, of your `selectCar.php` PHP is?

Comment: @Bonatti I have edited the question to show

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json"` – by that you are telling PHP that you were sending JSON (which you actually aren’t even though), and PHP will not populate $_POST in such a case.

Comment: @CBroe I removed it and the error is gone but it is responding with an empty array

Comment: Please learn to do some basic debugging … It should not be the main purpose of this site, to hold people’s hand regarding that all day long. Had you made a simple debug output of what `$_POST['selectedName']` contains, you would probably have noticed, that the value has double quotes around it - which is the result of you encoding it as JSON. `data: { selectedName: selectedName }` is what you should send - normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, there is no need to involve JSON here on the sending end (especially not, if you don’t really know what you are doing to begin with.)